# iPhone External Accessory Framework

Tags: ios, bluetooth, mfi

I want to build an app that can communicate to some external hardware. I come to know that External Accessory framework will help me connect and communicate with my hardware, but I have few confusions on it.

Do I need to register ‘Made For iPod’ program before I start?

My external hardware is 2D wearable Scanner.

Comment: You can use Core Bluetooth but it has limited throughput. If you need more throughput then you will need to go through MFi

Comment: @Paulw ,I definitely need more throughput ,on MFI which enrollment i want to choose ,either developer , or manufacturer , my external hardware is ready , i don't know which enrollment  i have to choose .please say that information about that

Comment: You will need to join the MFi development program but changes may be required to your hardware if your manufacturer isn't already a member of the MFi program; information on which license you need is here https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#2-2

Comment: @Paulw,Is there any way to access my external hardware  without using MFI Program

Comment: Only using Core Bluetooth or Wifi

Comment: @Paulw , i want to use core bluetooth only

Comment: Ok then that limits you to the GATT profile with Bluetooth low Energy. The data rate is limited as you can only send 20 bytes per packet